# gitpython returns 'git push --porcelain origin' returned with exit code 128

Tags: python, gitpython

I'm trying to push a new git repo upstream using gitpython module. Below are the steps that I'm doing and get an error 128.

```
# Initialize a local git repo
init_repo = Repo.init(gitlocalrepodir+"%s" %(gitinitrepo))

# Add a file to this new local git repo
init_repo.index.add([filename])

# Initial commit
init_repo.index.commit('Initial Commit - %s' %(timestr))

# Create remote
init_repo.create_remote('origin', giturl+gitinitrepo+'.git')

# Push upstream (Origin)
init_repo.remotes.origin.push()
```

While executing the push(), gitpython throws an exception:

```
'git push --porcelain origin' returned with exit code 128
```

Access to github is via SSH.

Do you see anything wrong that I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

I tracked it down with a similar approach:

```
class ProgressPrinter(git.RemoteProgress):

    def line_dropped(self, line):
        print("line dropped : " + str(line))
```

Which you can then call in your code:

```
init_repo.remotes.origin.push(progress=ProgressPrinter())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the output from the git command.

Given this Progress class:

```
class Progress(git.RemoteProgress):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()

        self.__all_dropped_lines = []

    def update( self, op_code, cur_count, max_count=None, message='' ):
        pass

    def line_dropped( self, line ):
        if line.startswith( 'POST git-upload-pack' ):
            return

        self.__all_dropped_lines.append( line )

    def allErrorLines( self ):
        return self.error_lines() + self.__all_dropped_lines

    def allDroppedLines( self ):
        return self.__all_dropped_lines
```

You can write code like this:

```
progress = Progress()

try:
    for info in remote.push( progress=progress ):
        # call info_callback with the push commands info
        info_callback( info )

    for line in progress.allDroppedLines():
        log.info( line )

except GitCommandError:
    for line in progress.allErrorLines():
        log.error( line )

    raise
```

When you run with this you will still get the 128 error, but you will also have the output og git to explain the problem.

Comment: Couple of items that are not clear from your code snippet. 1. You didn't supply any arguments when you instantiated `Progress()` 2. What is `info_callback(info)` supposed to do?